# Android Kotlin Dividing two Double type numbers yields an incorrect result with bad accuracy

Tags: android, kotlin, precision, divide

Having a problem dividing two double number types. I'm after exact values so rounding is not really desirable.

I have a UI field where data is pulled represented by the 'value' variable, and dividing it by another value to get an exact percentage. The first line is what I intend to use the rest the debug output I was experimenting with. The correct answer is 0.109* and I can only seem to get the correct answer when assigning the values directly and not from variable assignment.

```
data.used = (value.text.toString().toDouble() / data.value)
var n1: Double = value.text.toString().toDouble()
var d1: Double = data.value
var n: Double = 120.0
var d: Double = 1100.0
Log.d("TEST", "n1($n1)/d1($d1) = ${n1/d1} ")
Log.d("TEST", "n1($n1)/d1($d1) = ${n1.div(d1)} ")
Log.d("TEST", "n($n)/d($d) = ${n/d} ")
Log.d("TEST", "n1($n1)/d($d) = ${n1/d} ")
```

This is the logcat output:

> D/TEST: n1(120.0)/d1(1110.0) = 0.10810810810810811

> D/TEST: n1(120.0)/d1(1110.0) = 0.10810810810810811

> D/TEST: n(120.0)/d(1100.0) = 0.10909090909090909

> D/TEST: n1(120.0)/d(1100.0) = 0.10909090909090909

It appears the value coming from the a class is the culprit. I cannot use the data.value member through reassignment or otherwise.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It is unknown what `data.value` even is; this might be an `int` division in a `float` context - where `var d1: Double = data.value` might require an explicit cast. Convert to and use [`java.math.BigDecimal`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-decimal/) if you require more precision than `float` / `double` can offer.